A simple derivative after Binomial Theorem.
We define $u:=t^2-1$, I have problems to prove that $$\frac{\ d^{2n}}{\ dt^{2n}}u^n=(2n)!$$
My attempt
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\ d^{2n}}{dt^{2n}}[(t^2-1)^n]=&\frac{\ d^{2n}}{\ dt^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(-1)^kt^{2n-2k}\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^n
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(-1)^k\frac{\ d^{2n}}{\ dt^{2n}}
 (t)^{2n-2k}\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(2n)!}{(-2k)}t^{-2k}
\end{split}
$$
From this I cannot to conclude anythings. Any suggestions?

Do you have to use the binomial theorem?

You're making an error: for $k > 0,$ the $2n$th derivative of $t^{2n - 2k}$ is $0$. For instance, compute the fourth derivative of $x^2.$ This means that the only term that survives all the differentiation is the $k = 0$ term, for which the binomial term is just $1$, and you have differentiated $t^{2n}$ $2n$ times, which is $(2n)! \cdot 1$.

The function $(t^2-1)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ with the leading term equal $t^{2n},$ i.e. $$(t^2-1)^n=t^{2n}+\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}a_kx^k $$ The exact values of $a_k$ do not matter. The $2n$-th derivative is equal the $2n$-th derivative of $t^{2n}.$ Therefore the result is equal $(2n)!.$
The same reasoning is valid for the polynomial $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^N(t-c_k).$ The leading term is equal $t^N.$ Thus the $N$-th derivative is equal $N!
$
In both cases there is no need for determining the coefficients of lower order terms. In particular the binomial theorem is not essential in the solution.

Your error is that you did not correctly calculate the $2n^{\rm th}$ derivative of each term.  Recall that the power rule states
$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^n] = nx^{n-1},$$
but when $n = 0$, this becomes $$\frac{d}{dx}[1] = 0,$$ and successive derivatives will also be $0$.  So you should recognize that the $2n^{\rm th}$ order derivative of $t^{2n-2k}$ will equal $0$ except when $k = 0$.  Thus, your summation has only one remaining term.
Another way to see it is to write out some sample terms in the sum:
$$(t^2 - 1)^n = t^{2n} - n t^{2(n-1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} t^{2(n-2)} + \cdots.$$
If you take the $2n^{\rm th}$ derivative of each term, every term except for the first will vanish.
